# How to solve this C programming exercise?

Tags: c

This is my first time learning C. So I have to write a code that can find the second largest number from any inputted numbers.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x, max, max2;
    max = max2 = -1;

    while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF) {
        if (x > max) {
            max2 = max;
            max = x;
        } else if (x > max2) {
            max2 = x;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", max2);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, if I enter `1 2 3 4 5` here, the answer should be 4, as 4 is the second max number. But the code should work on any inputted number. I just couldn't figure it out.

I have to use Linux terminal and vim to solve it. I made a input file in terminal using `vim input` and made a file and input `1 2 3 4 5` there. But when I run the code using `./a.out <input`, it still shows 5. How do I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa. David *Lightman*? First it is simple C stuff, then it's [hacking into WOPR and nearly starting World War 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086567/). I think we should nip this in the bud right here.

Comment: introduce a variable `secondButMax` that gets assigned the current `max` value when this receives a new value because you have  found something bigger. And leave those nukes alone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438603/c-finding-second-largest-number-in-an-array , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396018/finding-the-largest-and-second-largest-number

Comment: @SouravGhosh I edited the details. But still it's not working. Can you please check where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I edited the details. But still it's not working. Can you please check my code?

Comment: @tofro it's not working :3

Comment: But your logic seems to be OK. Print value of x after every 'scanf' and make sure , all values are reading in your program. Also it will not works for  negative values properly.

Comment: @DavidLightman your code show `4` ([DEMO](http://ideone.com/yBqdYr) )

Comment: Do you rebuild `a.out`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the code worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I made it easy for myself and replaced your input with an array.

```
int main (void)
{
char lst [] = { 10, 11, 2, 33 };  // my input (must be char because 
  // I use sizeof to determine the number of inputs)

int max = -1;   // biggest
int submax = -1;  // 2nd biggest

if (sizeof (lst) < 2)  // must be > 1 to find 2 biggest numbers
{
    printf ("bad");
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (lst); i ++)
{
    int x = lst [i];
    if (x > max)
    {
        submax = max;
        max = x;  // new biggest makes the old biggest to 2nd biggest
    }
    else  // its not biggest but maybe 2nd biggest
    {
        if (x > submax)
        {
            submax = x;
        }
    }

    printf ("\n%d: check %d - max=%d, submax=%d\n", i, x, max, submax);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I cannot use an arrey. I have to make it without using an arrey.

Comment: Solved this problem. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Programming is not about hacking characters into a computer. It is about ideas and algorithms. Try to understand ... and then you will find it very easy to replace my array with your input.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "any inputted number" ? Non sorted input ? Negative as well ?
Here is a function which takes a list of positive integers and return the second maximum, or -1 if an error is encountered (not enough arguments). To adapt to your needs.

```
int snd_max(int length, int* args) {
    int max, max2;
    max = -1;
    max2 = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i< length; i++) {
        if (args[i] > max) {
            max2 = max;
            max = args[i];
        } else if (args[i] > max2 {
            max2 = args[i]
        }
    }
    return max2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I meant non sorted input.